# Reactjs Stripe payment not working with Node/Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for the first time in my react project.

I have set up a payment with the test api keys. I have been using Javascript and React for a few years now but I have no-to-little knowledge of node.js / express. So I used a boiler plate from sandbox for the backend, which you can see below;

```
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")("MY TEST KEY HAS BEEN INSERTED HERE");
const uuid = require("uuid/v4");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Add your Stripe Secret Key to the .require('stripe') statement!");
});

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Request:", req.body);

  let error;
  let status;
  try {
    const { product, token } = req.body;

    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: token.email,
      source: token.id
    });

    const idempotency_key = uuid();
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create(
      {
        amount: 8.00,
        currency: "gbp",
        customer: customer.id,
        receipt_email: token.email,
        description: `Purchased the ${product.name}`,
        name: token.card.name,
      },
      {
        idempotency_key
      }
    );
    console.log("Charge:", { charge });
    status = "success";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    status = "failure";
  }

  res.json({ error, status });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And here is the function within react js which handles the  even once the user has entered the card number etc.

```
  async function handleToken(token){

    let whichClass = {
      name: "Bodytone",
      price: 8.00
    }
   
    const response = await axios.post("https://s9mh5.sse.codesandbox.io/checkout", {token, whichClass});

    const { status } = response.data;

    if (status === "success") {
      alert("Successful payment");
    } else {
      alert("failed payment");
    }

  }
```

What I am finding is that when I click to send the payment after entering details, I see the green tick to suggest everything went smoothly. But within the stripe dashboard for this account, nothing shows as a result of the test payment.

In the console I see two different error messages logged, which are detailed below:

**StripeCheckout.open: Either 'token' or 'source' is a required option, but neither was found.
You can learn about the available configuration options in the Checkout docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout 0.chunk.js:108728:20**

As well as.....

```
**Uncaught TypeError: this.fn is not a function
    trigger https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:3
    bind https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:3
    onToken https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:3
    closed https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:3
    bind https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:3
    processMessage https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2
    bind https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2
    message https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2
    RPC https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2
checkout.js:3:24013**
```

Is anyone able to spot the mistake / error?

Your help and feedback are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using the [new Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) rather than the legacy one you're using now, or possibly Elements to build your own form, for which you could use https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js.

That said, you didn't provide enough client-side code to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hi @floatingLomas, thank you for the feedback and suggestion! I will look into that reccomendation for sure.